# opening jpg image after saving from ffmpeg not working

Tags: asp.net, image, c#-4.0, video, ffmpeg

In my project I am saving videos, converting formats to .swf using ffmpeg. Converting and saving the videos is working fine, but I have a problem with creating the thumbnails. It saves a "picture.jpg" but there is no image. looking at the thumbnail its only got the normal photoviewer sign which is fine, but when I try to open the image it gives a message of 
Windows photo viewer: Windows photo viewer cant open this picture because the file appears to be damaged, corrupted, or is too large. (this image is 2.7MB) - Photos taken from my camera is about 5MB and that opens.

PictureViewer: couldn't display "image.jpg" because a suitable graphics importer could not be found.

Paint: Paint cannot read this file. This is not a valid bitmap file or its format is currently not supported.
 The images won't open in any I done to save the image:

```
    protected void btnUploadVideo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string dtMonth = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM");
        string dtYear = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy");
        lblMsg.Visible = false;

        lblMsg.Visible = true;

        // Before attempting to save the file, verify
        // that the FileUpload control contains a file.
        if (fuPath.HasFile)
        {
            // Get the size in bytes of the file to upload.
            int fileSize = fuPath.PostedFile.ContentLength;

            // Allow only files less than 2,100,000 bytes (approximately 2 MB) to be uploaded.
            if (fileSize < 10497717)
            {
                // Call a helper method routine to save the file.
                SaveFile2();
            }
        }
        else
            // Notify the user that a file was not uploaded.
            lblMsg.Text = "You did not specify a file to upload.";
    }

    private void SaveFile2()
    {
        string dtMonth = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM");
        string dtYear = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy");

        if (fuPath != null || fuPath.PostedFile != null)
        {
            postedfilename = fuPath.PostedFile.FileName;
            SavePath = Server.MapPath("~\\Video\\");
            string NewFName = postedfilename;
            NewFName = NewFName.Substring(NewFName.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1, NewFName.Length - NewFName.LastIndexOf(".")) + "." + NewFName.Substring(NewFName.LastIndexOf(".") + 1);
            Filenamewithpath = SavePath + NewFName;
            string outputPath = Server.MapPath("~\\uploads\\" + dtYear + "\\" + dtMonth + "\\SWF\\");
            CreateDirectoryIfNotExists(SavePath);
            CreateDirectoryIfNotExists(outputPath);

            //Save The file
            fuPath.PostedFile.SaveAs(Filenamewithpath);

            //Start Converting
            string inputfile, outputfile, filargs;
            string withoutext;

            //Get the file name without Extension
            withoutext = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Filenamewithpath);

            //Input file path of uploaded image
            inputfile = SavePath + NewFName;

            //output file format in swf

            outputfile = outputPath + withoutext + ".swf";
            Session["outputfile"] = withoutext + ".swf";
            //file orguments for FFMEPG

            // Create the path and file name to check for duplicates.
            string pathToCheck = outputfile;

            // Create a temporary file name to use for checking duplicates.
            string tempfileName = "";

            // Check to see if a file already exists with the
            // same name as the file to upload.        
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(pathToCheck))
            {
                int counter = 2;
                while (System.IO.File.Exists(pathToCheck))
                {
                    // if a file with this name already exists,
                    // prefix the filename with a number.
                    tempfileName = outputPath + counter.ToString() + withoutext + ".swf";
                    pathToCheck = tempfileName;
                    counter++;
                }

                outputfile = tempfileName;
                // Notify the user that the file name was changed.
                lblMsg.Text = "A file with the same name already exists." +
                    "<br />Your file was saved as " + counter.ToString() + withoutext + ".swf";
            }

            filargs = "-i " + inputfile + " -ar 22050 " + outputfile;

            string spath;
            spath = Server.MapPath(".");
            Process proc;
            proc = new Process();
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = spath + "\\ffmpeg\\ffmpeg.exe";
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = filargs;
            proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
            try
            {

                proc.Start();
                fuPath.PostedFile.SaveAs(outputfile);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex.Message);
            }
            proc.WaitForExit();
            proc.Close();

            //Create Thumbs 

            string thumbPath, thumbName;
            string thumbargs;

            thumbPath = Server.MapPath("~\\uploads\\" + dtYear + "\\" + dtMonth + "\\Thumb\\");
            CreateDirectoryIfNotExists(thumbPath);

            thumbName = thumbPath + withoutext + ".jpg";

            // Create the path and file name to check for duplicates.
            string thumbPathToCheck = thumbName;

            // Create a temporary file name to use for checking duplicates.
            string thumbTempfileName = "";

            // Check to see if a file already exists with the
            // same name as the file to upload.        
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(thumbPathToCheck))
            {
                int counter = 2;
                while (System.IO.File.Exists(thumbPathToCheck))
                {
                    // if a file with this name already exists,
                    // prefix the filename with a number.
                    thumbTempfileName = thumbPath + counter.ToString() + withoutext + ".jpg";
                    thumbPathToCheck = thumbTempfileName;
                    counter++;
                }

                thumbName = thumbTempfileName;
                // Notify the user that the file name was changed.
                lblMsg.Text = "A file with the same name already exists." +
                    "<br />Your file was saved as " + counter.ToString() + withoutext + ".jpg";
            }

            //thumbargs = "-i " + inputfile + " -an -ss 00:00:03 -s 120×90 -vframes 1 -f mjpeg " + thumbName;
           // thumbargs = "-i " + inputfile + "-f image2 -ss 1.000 -vframes 1 " + thumbName;
            thumbargs = "-i " + inputfile + " -vframes 1 -ss 00:00:10 -s 150x150 " + thumbName;

            //  thumbargs = "ffmpeg -i" + inputfile + " -ss 0:00:01.000 -sameq -vframes 1 " + withoutext + ".jpg";
            //  thumbargs = "-i " + inputfile + " -vframes 1 -ss 00:00:07 -s 150x150 " + thumbName;
            Process thumbproc = new Process();
            thumbproc.StartInfo.FileName = spath + "\\ffmpeg\\ffmpeg.exe";
            thumbproc.StartInfo.Arguments = thumbargs;
            thumbproc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            thumbproc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            thumbproc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;

            string data = "";                

            try
            {
                fuPath.PostedFile.SaveAs(thumbName);
                thumbproc.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex.Message);
            }

            thumbproc.WaitForExit();
            thumbproc.Close();
            File.Delete(inputfile);
            lblMsg.Text = "Video Uploaded Successfully";
            hyp.Visible = true;
            hyp.NavigateUrl = "WatchVideo.aspx";

            SaveToDB(outputfile, thumbName);
        }
    }
```

EDIT:
If it is the thumbargs, I have tried a few ways, but with no success:

```
     //thumbargs = "-i " + inputfile + " -an -ss 00:00:03 -s 120×90 -vframes 1 -f mjpeg " + thumbName;
     // thumbargs = "-i " + inputfile + "-f image2 -ss 1.000 -vframes 1 " + thumbName;
      thumbargs = "-i " + inputfile + " -vframes 1 -ss 00:00:10 -s 150x150 " + thumbName;
     //  thumbargs = "ffmpeg -i" + inputfile + " -ss 0:00:01.000 -sameq -vframes 1 " + withoutext + ".jpg";
```

This is how it looks when saved, but can't open....
[image]

EDIT:

I tried adding the argument to the command prompt to see if it works there but it gave me a message of : [NULL @ 000000000025f7a0] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'vframes'
vframes: invalid argument
The line I used:

```
    ffmpeg -i VID2012.3GP vframes 1 VID2012.jpg
```

If it is that it is not set correctly in IIS how do I set it?

EDIT:
I changed a bit of my code. Debugging through my code there is no exception that is thrown, but if I point the mouse over the process (after it started) it "shows an exception of type System.InvalidOperationException"

```
    thumbargs = "-i " + postedfilename + " vframes 1" + thumbName;
            ProcessStartInfo thumbProcstartIfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            thumbProcstartIfo.FileName = @"\ffmpeg\ffmpeg.exe";
            thumbProcstartIfo.Arguments = thumbargs;
            thumbProcstartIfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            thumbProcstartIfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            thumbProcstartIfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;

            try
            {
                using (var process = new Process())
                {
                    process.StartInfo = thumbProcstartIfo;
                    process.Start();
                    process.WaitForExit();
                }
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
            {
                lblMsg.Text = ex.ToString();
            }
```

Comment: Is there some reason why you call `thumbproc = new Process()` twice? Not sure if it's relevant to your problem but doesn't look right.

Comment: Hi.. That was a mistake, but taking it out still doesn't make the image work....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it has to do with these lines:

```
thumbproc.Start();
fuPath.PostedFile.SaveAs(thumbname);
```

I expect that the second line saves the uploaded file to your data directory and the first line starts processing the file. Shouldn't these line be swapped?

```
fuPath.PostedFile.SaveAs(thumbname);
thumbproc.Start();
```

Comment: Hi Raimond, thanks for the reply, but it makes no difference on the image. it still doesn't work....

Comment: Hi Raimond, thanks for the reply, no that isn't the problem, I removed all the characters (% - ) but still not working.....

Comment: Can you save the movie file that you're uploading and verify that this works?

Comment: Yes, the movie file works great, it converts, saves and plays perfect after it was converted. It's only the images that is not working....

Comment: can you post the complete code? I can't see where inputfile  is defined.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30826/discussion-between-raimond-kuipers-and-user2042152)

Comment: just letting you know, the error was that there was a space in a folder name and had to add double quotes where my path was declared....